# How to automate bash scripts which includes sudo commands?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, root

I added some commands to the bash script and those commands need root permission. So then I added sudo keyword to those commands. As the normal way, I added this script to the crontab file to automate my task.

Is there any way to give root access when it tries to run automatically?

Note: I'm using crontab to automate my script.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If one of the answers below solves your problem please mark that answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Read `man sudoers sudoedit`. You can give a single user passwordless access to a set of commands. You can specify a date range for the access, so if your script is only run between 03:00 and 03:15, you can allow access only then.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you need *other* commands in the script to run as a non-root user, the simplest option is to remove the `sudo` commands from inside the script, and run the whole thing as root either by adding it to root's crontab file (`sudo crontab -e`) or via the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file specifying `root` in the user field.

If you *do* need to run some commands as a non-root user, then you can do the same but drop privileges for those specific commands using `sudo -u <otheruser>`